# document.getElementById().innerHTML isn't working, but I can log the value of that element to the console. What's going on?

Tags: javascript, html, forms, dom

I am currently re-writing a small project in which a charitable organisation based in Australia is scored against a series of questions. Previously, the HTML was poorly formatted with no form tags, no indentation, etc. so I decided to re-write it based on what I had learned about HTML forms at university. However, the method I had previously been using to change blank HTML placeholder paragaraphs into text (explaining the score for each question, and the total score) is no longer working with the new HTML and JS. The values of name and state are both logged to the console but the HTML does not change as expected. Here's the code:

```js
function getNameOfOrganisation () {
    let organisation = document.getElementById("nameOfOrganisation").value;
    return organisation;
}

function getStateOfOrganisation () {
    let state = document.getElementById("state").value;
    if (state === "VIC") {
        let points = 1;
        return points;
    } else if (state === "NSW") {
        let points = 0.5;
        return points;
    } else {
        let points = 0;
        return points;
    }
}

function main () {
    let name = getNameOfOrganisation();
    document.getElementById("namePlaceholder").innerHTML = "Name of organisation: " + name;
    console.log(name);
    let state = getStateOfOrganisation();
    document.getElementById("statePlaceholder").innerHTML = "Points scored for state/territory: " + state;
    console.log(state);
}
```

```html
<h1>Organisation Score Calculator</h1>
<form action="">
    <h4>Input the name of the charity.</h4>
    <input type="text" id="nameOfOrganisation">
    <h4>Which state/territory does this organisation service?</h4>
    <select name="state" id="state">
        <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
        <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
        <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
        <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
        <option value="NT">NT</option>
        <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
        <option value="WA">WA</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <button onclick="main()">Get score!</button>
    <p id="namePlaceholder"></p>
    <p id="statePlaceholder"></p>
</form>
```

I thought it was an issue to do with the Javascript loading before the HTML, or something along those lines (forgive me for any language mistakes please) as I had seen others on this website with almost my issue exactly solve their problems by changing the location of the script tag in the HTML. This did not help.

Comment: When you add a `<button>` inside of a `<form>`, clicking it will automatically submit your form, causing your page to refresh. To stop the form from submitting add `type="button"` to your `<button>`, which will keep the changes made by the JS (of course if you do this, then you need to handle submitting the data to the server in another way if that is something you need to do).

Comment: change ```main``` to ```main(e)``` and inside the function, at the first line, add ```e.preventDefault()```

Comment: There is no point in using a `<form>` element when you don’t intend the form to be submitted as an HTTP request. Drop it.

Comment: To add more to @user3840170 's comment, you broke the code by adding the `form` tags. Button and other 'form` content elements have not needed a form container since HTML3.

Answer (score 0):

1- consider sending the event when you click the button to prevent the page from reloading and losing your data `<button onclick="main(event)">Get score!</button>`

2- add `e.preventDefault();` to main function to tell the page not to reload

```js
function getNameOfOrganisation() {
  let organisation = document.getElementById("nameOfOrganisation").value;
  return organisation;
}

function getStateOfOrganisation() {
  let state = document.getElementById("state").value;
  if (state === "VIC") {
    let points = 1;
    return points;
  } else if (state === "NSW") {
    let points = 0.5;
    return points;
  } else {
    let points = 0;
    return points;
  }
}

function main(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  let name = getNameOfOrganisation();
  document.getElementById("namePlaceholder").innerHTML = "Name of organisation: " + name;
  let state = getStateOfOrganisation();
  document.getElementById("statePlaceholder").innerHTML = "Points scored for state/territory: " + state;
}
```

```html
<h1>Organisation Score Calculator</h1>
<form action="">
  <h4>Input the name of the charity.</h4>
  <input type="text" id="nameOfOrganisation">
  <h4>Which state/territory does this organisation service?</h4>
  <select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button onclick="main(event)">Get score!</button>
  <p id="namePlaceholder"></p>
  <p id="statePlaceholder"></p>
</form>
```

Answer (score -1):

Consider this

```js
function getNameOfOrganisation() {
  return document.getElementById("nameOfOrganisation").value;
}

function getStateOfOrganisation() {
  const state = document.getElementById("state").value;

  if (state === "VIC") {
    return 1;
  } else if (state === "NSW") {
    return 0.5;
  } else {
    return 0;
  }
}

function log(e) {
  document.getElementById("statePlaceholder").innerHTML = "Points scored for state/territory:" + getStateOfOrganisation();
  document.getElementById("namePlaceholder").innerHTML = "Name of organisation: " + getNameOfOrganisation();
}

log();

const form = document.getElementById("form");

form.addEventListener("submit", (e) => {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevent the actual submit for demonstration purposes, in real world app you'd want to remove this
  
  const data = new FormData(e.target);
  console.log('submitting:', [...data.entries()]);
    
  log();
});
```

```html
<h1>Organisation Score Calculator</h1>
<form id="form" action="">
  <h4>Input the name of the charity.</h4>
  <input type="text" id="nameOfOrganisation" name="nameOfOrganisation">
  <h4>Which state/territory does this organisation service?</h4>
  <select name="state" id="state">
    <option value="VIC">VIC</option>
    <option value="NSW">NSW</option>
    <option value="ACT">ACT</option>
    <option value="QLD">QLD</option>
    <option value="NT">NT</option>
    <option value="TAS">TAS</option>
    <option value="WA">WA</option>
  </select>
  <br>
  <br>
  <button type="submit">Get score!</button>
  <p id="namePlaceholder"></p>
  <p id="statePlaceholder"></p>
</form>
```